# Controlling the depth of iptables RETURN (or how to skip chains)

Tags: iptables

I have the following setup for iptables

```
INPUT
    ParentChain
        ChildChain1
        ChildChain2

   ... More Rules on INPUT ....
```

How can I return from ChildChain1 back to INPUT just after ParentChain?
My understanding RETURN target from ChildChain1 will come out into ParentChain at ChildChain2?
How can I RETURN say 2 levels?

My understanding is if i JUMP to INPUT and there are no matches, I will end up back in ChildChain1 (and eventually hit ChidlChain2 which I am essentially trying to skip)

Comment: I think your firewall is getting too complicated. Can't you make it simpler?

Comment: There are programmatic elements to the firewall. I can move the complexity into code, however being able to skip a chain/return to INPUT in the firewall is the simplest solution if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Glueon, in that you really should reconsider your iptables rules, seems unnecessarily complex.

That said, there ***is*** a way to do what you want. I'll just give an example:

```
-A INPUT <some_matches_here> -j ParentChain
...
-A ParentChain <some_matches_here> -g ChildChain1
...
```

The `-g` switch orders `netfilter` to perform a `GOTO` instead of `JUMP` to the target chain. Therefore, the 'call stack' when filtering branches to ChildChain1 still records `INPUT` as the 'calling chain'. At the end of ChildChain1, if no matches result in a 'terminating target', netfilter will revert to the INPUT chain.

**NOTE:** I haven't actually tested this, but based on my knowledge of `iptables`, it should work that way.